# Meaning of rational transfer function underlying MATLAB filter or Scipy.signal filter

Tags: c#, matlab, filter, signal-processing, transfer-function

I have some MATLAB code that filters an input signal using `filter`:

```matlab
CUTOFF = 0.05;
FS = 5000;
[b, a] = butter(1, CUTOFF / (FS / 2), 'high');
% b = [0.99996859, -0.99996859]
% a = [1.0, -0.99993717]
dataAfter = filter(b, a, dataBefore);
```

I'm trying to convert this code to C#. I have already got the `butter` function to work pretty fast, but now I'm stuck converting the `filter` function.

I have read the [MATLAB filter](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) documentation and [Python Scipy.signal filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) documentation, but there is a term present in the transfer function definition that I don't understand.

Here is the "rational transfer function" definition from the linked documentation:

```
        b[0] + b[1]z^(-1)  + ... + b[M]z^(-M)
Y(z) = _______________________________________ X(z)
        a[0] + a[1]z^(-1)  + ... + a[N]z^(-N)
```

Correct me if i'm wrong, but `z` is the current element of input data, and `Y(z)` is the output?

If the above this is true, **what is `X(z)` in this equation?**

I want to understand this to implement it in C#, if there is an equivalent option then please enlighten me.

Comment: I believe it may be a time delay function, ref. [these Cal Tech notes](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/courses/cds101/fa04/caltech/am04_ch6-3nov04.pdf), example 6.2 and the description of figure 6.8. Note: I have no expertise here, have only ever used the transfer function in Simulink which doesn't require the `X` function.

Comment: X is the input signal X(z) is the z transform of X and z is the unit shift operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`More About`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) section of the matlab docs as you pointed out, they describe:

> The input-output description of the filter operation on a vector in the Z-transform domain is a rational transfer function. A rational transfer function is of the form,

```
        b[0] + b[1]z^(-1)  + ... + b[M]z^(-M)
Y(z) = _______________________________________ X(z)
        a[0] + a[1]z^(-1)  + ... + a[N]z^(-N)
```

Rearranging:

```
       Y(z)   b[0] + b[1]z^(-1)  + ... + b[M]z^(-M)
H(z) = ____ = _______________________________________
       X(z)   a[0] + a[1]z^(-1)  + ... + a[N]z^(-N)
```

Thus, `X(z)` is the [`z-domain`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Definition) transform of the input vector `x` (see[`Digital Filter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter)). It is important to mention that, also in the docs they give an alternate representation of the transfer function as a [`difference equation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Difference_equation)

[image]

Which lends itself better to be ported into code. One possible implementation in `C#`, could be ([`using this answer as reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34459298/6383857))

```
public static double[] Filter(double[] b, double[] a, double[] x)
{
   // normalize if a[0] != 1.0. TODO: check if a[0] == 0
   if(a[0] != 1.0)
   {
       a = a.Select(el => el / a[0]).ToArray();
       b = b.Select(el => el / a[0]).ToArray();
   }

   double[] result = new double[x.Length];
   result[0] = b[0] * x[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < x.Length; i++)
   {
       result[i] = 0.0;
       int j = 0;
       if ((i < b.Length) && (j < x.Length))
       {
           result[i] += (b[i] * x[j]);
       }
       while(++j <= i)
       {
            int k = i - j;
            if ((k < b.Length) && (j < x.Length))
            {
                result[i] += b[k] * x[j];
            }
            if ((k < x.Length) && (j < a.Length))
            {
                result[i] -= a[j] * result[k];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Driver**:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] dataBefore = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    double[] b = { 0.99996859, -0.99996859 };
    double[] a = { 1.0, -0.99993717 };

    var dataAfter = Filter(b1, a, dataBefore);
}
```

**Output**

```
Matlab dataAfter = [0.99996859 1.999874351973491  2.999717289867956  3.999497407630634]
CSharp dataAfter = [0.99996859 1.9998743519734905 2.9997172898679563 3.999497407630634]
```

**UPDATE**
If the coefficient vectors `a` and `b` have a fixed length of 2 the filtering function can be simplified to:

```
public static double[] Filter(double[] b, double[] a, double[] x)
{
    // normalize if a[0] != 1.0. TODO: check if a[0] == 0
    if (a[0] != 1.0)
    {
        a = a.Select(el => el / a[0]).ToArray();
        b = b.Select(el => el / a[0]).ToArray();
    }

    int length = x.Length;
    double z = 0.0;
    double[] y = new double[length];    // output filtered signal

    double b0 = b[0];
    double b1 = b[1];
    double a1 = a[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        y[i] = b0 * x[i] + z;
        z = b1 * x[i] - a1 * y[i];
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the implementation! 
But it's very very SLOW. We are talking several minutes (ish).

Comment: The size of my input data (x) is 240001, so the nested while loop is killing the performance.

Comment: @Bjqn is the size of `b` and `a` fixed?

Comment: Yes b and a will always have a length of 2

Comment: @Bjqn I've added an update to my answer to have an optimized version when the coefficient vectors both have fixed length of `2`. If this approach doesn't cut it you might need to try other approaches see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24418028/6383857)

Comment: Thank you so much! 
The updated implementation works really really well and output is as close to MATLAB as it will ever get :D 
And I actually understand the updated version really well and can relate it to the alterned transfer function. :D

Comment: @Bjqn awesome! Glad I could help.